# Como puede crear esta figura de asceriscos en php?

Tags: php, asterisk

tengo que hacer un ejercicio, basicamente crear una figura de asceriscos en php, con bucles for explicitamente. Además me pide que la altura sea de 5, o sea si cambio este valor la figura debe permanecer acorde con los valores cambiados y no deformarse. Tengo un codigo escrito, pero solo me sale un triangulo, necesito completarlo para que me salga la figura completa. Este es mi codigo:

```
<?php
$alto = 5;

for ($i=0; $i<=$alto; $i++) { 
    for ($j=$alto-$i; $j>=1; $j--) {  
        echo "* ";  
    }
        echo "<br>";
    
    } 
?>
```

Resultado:
[image: Resultado del Código]

Y la figura a crear es:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Porque no haces otro `for` similar al que ya tienes con la variable j, y lo ajustas para que te imprima los demás asteriscos que necesitas?

Answer (score 3):

La "complejidad" con este algoritmo está en que los triángulos visualmente están balanceados compartiendo un punto en común en el medio (ya sea `*` o `espacio`). En otras palabras, el **último caracter** del primer triángulo es el **primer caracter** del segundo triángulo.

Mi propuesta es, modificando un poco tu código, agregar un bloque `if/else`. Si el contador `$j == $alto` es porque es el principio del segundo triángulo y omita ese caracter para hacer el balance. Luego el siguiente `if` calcula las `*` que tiene que imprimir a ambos lados del "*hueco*" que hay en medio.

```php
<?php
$alto = 5;

for ($i=0; $i<$alto; $i++) {
    for ($j=$alto*2; $j>0; $j--) {
        if ($j == $alto) {
            continue;
        } elseif (($j > $alto+$i) or ($j < $alto-$i+1)) {
            echo "* ";
        } else {
            echo "  "; // [!] Ver nota al final
        }
    }
    echo "<br />".PHP_EOL;
}
```

`[!]` NOTA. Lo más probable es que en el navegador no se vea correctamente, a pesar de que si está funcionando, si lo ejecutas en la consola sirve perfecto. Lo que pasa es que HTML omite multiples espacios seguidos. Para arreglarlo tendrás que usar alguna técnica para [imprimir múltiples espacios](https://www.google.com/search?q=html+insert+multiple+spaces) en html.

Comment: Si en el navegador no se ve correctamente lo puedes encerrar todo en etiquetas `<pre></pre>`. *El texto en un elemento <pre> se muestra en una fuente de ancho fijo y el texto conserva tanto los espacios como los saltos de línea.* (traducido de [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp))